# Show Table of Contents step by steps in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, slideshow

I was wondering if there is any way to make the items in the table of contents of beamer to appear in steps. I use `\tableofcontents` in my first frame, but I want them to appear one by one, with pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> for example.

Comment: `\tableofcontents[pausesections]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Ferrari Drivers' Champions}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[pausesections]
\end{frame}

\section{Alberto Ascari}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} 

\section{Juan Manuel Fangio}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} 

\section{Mike Hawthorn}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} 

\section{Phil Hill}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} 

\section{John Surtees}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} 

\section{Niki Lauda}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} 

\section{Jody Scheckter}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} 

\section{Michael Schumacher}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} 

\section{Kimi Räikkönen}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```